# Is there a name for a filtering index for search

Tags: javascript, c#

Is there a name for the pattern of creating a search index for filtering/sorting/paging then just having the your javascript request a list of ids (found in the index)?

Some back story:

I've got a pretty common requirement to create a list of products for filtering, sorting and paging.

My normal method of going about this is to have my back end create what I've self labeled an index, which is basically just a json list of objects with the id and filter/sort variables.  I can pretty easily filter/sort/slice(page) the list to get what I want, then just ajax back to the server to get the full product information by id.  It seems to work fine for lists where I have under a few thousand items (10k json payload), so I've never questioned it.

This seems like it's a pretty obvious solution but when describing it to my coworkers they seem genuinely surprised that I'm not passing my filter/sort/page parameters all the way back to the web server and then translating it and sending it over to a SQL server to execute some horrifically complex query.

Does the thing I've described have a name?  I just internally call it an index but my google-fu is weak and I can't seem to find anyone online to back me up as not crazy for doing things this way.  (Is this a terrible idea for reasons I've maybe not seen?)

Comment: I think you'll generally see better performance by doing the data selection/filtering at the SQL level rather than the application. SQL tends to be pretty optimized to do that sort of thing. You can imagine how returning all data and then doing your filtering and sorting in the application would scale poorly.

Comment: Also, any time you can avoid sending a request to the server, you should do that. It'll make for a better user experience and reduce bandwidth. In the method you're using, it seems like there's an additional request going on.

Comment: @Nick It's the same number of requests.  First request is a very simple and highly cached "select filter fields from table".  
The follow up requests are just GetByID queries that are also heavily cached.
I find you get a lot more performance/reuse out of a cached GetByID request that's used from many places on a site than a highly optimized query with a half dozen parameters.